# Cannot activate a file with chinese path when using ZeroBrane remote debugging

Tags: remote-debugging, zerobrane

I created a folder named "新建文件夹" on windows desktop and tried to use remote debugging. Then the zerobrane prompted the following:

> Debugging suspended at 'c:/users/mixwind/desktop/싐ꢽ쓎ﺼ킼//test.mcs:1'
>   (couldn't activate the file).

I guess windows encode Chinese characters as GBK and zerobrane encode to UTF8?

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple fix for this issue; you can consider one of the following options:

1. patch Lua or load modules that handle Unicode names; see for example this [patch for Lua 5.1](https://bitbucket.org/doub/electronmeat/src/tip/srcweb/lua-5.1.4/lua-wstring.patch?fileviewer=file-view-default);
2. use short names when possible; this should work with the IDE;
3. avoid Unicode names.

See [this ticket](https://github.com/pkulchenko/ZeroBraneStudio/issues/559) for further details and the discussion.